# How to make a PUT request without appending /edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2.14 app.
In this app I am using the FullCalendar jQuery plugin. When I move an event
in the calendar a function is triggered which is supposed to update the record.

The problem is that I am trying to do a PUT but somehow the Ajax call makes a put BUT adds /edit at the end of the url.

```
Started PUT "/sv/admin/projects/4/tasks/4/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-05 09:15:51 +0100
```

This is my Ajax code:

```
updateEvent = function(the_event) {
      data = { starts_at: the_event.start, ends_at: the_event.end };
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: "/admin/projects/<%= @project.id %>/tasks/" + the_event.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        //data: JSON.stringify(data, { _method:'put' }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
          alert("YEAY");
        }
      });
    };
```

This is my update method in Rails:

```
def update
    @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
    if @task.valid?
      flash[:notice] = (t "notice_task_success")
      redirect_to edit_admin_project_task_path(@project)
    else
      flash[:error] = "#{(t 'notice_error')}"
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The strange thing is if I add an invalid attribute to the data object it makes a normal PUT (without appending /edit).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: This might be related to the fact that the update action is done with a PUT request in Rails, which is the /:resource_id/edit kind of route. Rails might append it when it sees that a put request is issued.